# Native Back Button Crashes in NavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have simply two viewcontrollers. ViewController connected to each other with NavigationController. The first one basically has only a textfield and tableview, the second viewcontroller has only scrollview. So far so good.

My application basically get user input and added to tableview in the first controller. user input is city name, and app provides detailed weather information in the scrollview. Once user click on add button, it takes user to second viewcontroller, which is scrollview.

App crashes when I scroll in the second viewcontroller then click native back button. Does any of you have any idea why this happen? By the way, if I do not scroll, then click back app does not crash.

My Project solution could be downloaded from [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2Yf2EqUAx61RGUtcGREMXJSYzQ/edit)

Here is the crash screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: What crash logs you got?

Comment: Setting the delegate of `scrollView` to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear` of `ViewController.m` seems to fix the crash. At least on my end. Try doing that.